# Displaying sudoku program in python

Tags: python, sudoku

I have to update a nested list sudoku with grids and borders. My output is not printing as intended and I am not sure how to fix it. This is my code with the test input cases and intended output vs output right now.

The code below has the following:

1. There are three nested sudoku lists that I need to update with grid lines and borders.
2. Next is my code and the intended output for the three sudoku boards.
3. Lastly, the link has my output right now

This is the description:

> Prints a given board to the console in a way that aligns the content of columns and makes the subgrids visible.
> Input : a Sudoku board (board) of size 4x4, 9x9, or 16x16
> Effect: prints the board to the console

```
small = [[0, 0, 1, 0],
         [4, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 2],
         [0, 3, 0, 0]]

big = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0],
       [7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6],
       [0, 2, 0, 3, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0],
       [8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 1, 6, 4, 0, 9, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2]]

giant = [[0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 16],
         [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 4, 0, 0, 7, 15, 0, 8, 0],
         [13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 5, 10, 0, 0],
         [0, 11, 12, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 3, 4, 0, 13],
         [15, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 11, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 9],
         [4, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 15, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 15, 0, 6, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0],
         [3, 0, 15, 4, 0, 13, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 7, 8],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [11, 0, 16, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0],
         [0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 15, 16, 0, 9, 0, 1],
         [9, 0, 2, 0, 0, 14, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7],
         [8, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 1, 2, 14, 11, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 16, 0, 6, 0, 12, 0, 0]]

import math

def print_board(board):
    board_size = len(board)
    l = int(board_size + math.sqrt(board_size) + 1)
    section = int(math.sqrt(board_size))
    border = 0
    i_index = 0

    for i in range(0, l):
        if (i == border):
            print('-' * l)
            border = border + section + 1
        else:
            inner_border = 0
            j_index = 0
            for j in range(0, l):
                if (j == inner_border):
                    print('|', end='')
                    inner_border = inner_border + section + 1
                else:
                    if (board[i_index][j_index] == 0):
                        print(' ', end='')
                    else:
                        if (board[i_index][j_index] < 10):
                            print(board[i_index][j_index], end='')
                        if (board[i_index][j_index] == 10):
                            print('A', end='')
                        if (board[i_index][j_index] == 11):
                            print('B', end='')
                        if (board[i_index][j_index] == 12):
                            print('C', end='')
                        if (board[i_index][j_index] == 13):
                            print('D', end='')
                        if (board[i_index][j_index] == 14):
                            print('E', end='')
                        if (board[i_index][j_index] == 15):
                            print('F', end='')
                        if (board[i_index][j_index] == 16):
                            print('G', end='')
                    j_index = j_index + 1
            i_index = i_index + 1


print(print_board(small))

print(print_board(big))

print(print_board(giant))
```

Intended output:

```
    -------
    |  |1 |
    |4 |  |
    -------
    |  | 2|
    | 3|  |
    -------
    >>> print_board(big)
    -------------
    |   |   |   |
    |4  |789|   |
    |78 |   | 56|
    -------------
    | 2 |36 |8  |
    |  5|  7| 1 |
    |8  |2  |  5|
    -------------
    |  1|64 |97 |
    |   |9  |   |
    |   | 3 |  2|
    -------------
    >>> print_board(giant2)
    ---------------------
    | 5  | 4 8| 6  |  9G|
    |1   |   D|4  7|F 8 |
    |D   | 73 |   9|5A  |
    | BCF|A   |  5 |34 D|
    ---------------------
    |F 13|  72|    | 5  |
    |   C| 3 5| B E|   9|
    |47  |    |C FG|    |
    |    |E F |69  |  C |
    ---------------------
    |3 F4| DE |   1|  78|
    |    |    |  9A|    |
    |B GA|    | 7  | 35 |
    |  D |    |E GF| 9 1|
    ---------------------
    |9 2 | E 4|8   |    |
    | E  |   A|9 3 |  17|
    |8   |G  1|2EB4|   3|
    |   1|  5 | G 6| C  |
    ---------------------
```

My output:

[My_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taoel.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print a newline character between each row, easiest way to do it is to use `print()` when you want to create a new line.

try this:

```
# ...
i_index = i_index + 1
print()
# ...
```

When you increase the `i_index` parameter you are basically going over to the next line, so this is where you want your `print()` statement as well

Also, since you are using `print` inside the function `print_board()`, you don't need to use `print(print_board(big))` for example, you should just use `print_board(big)`. that is why you are seeing `None` printed between each board (because `print_board()` returns None)